# explosion sound thread in MFC game project is stopping the music that is playing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Mabye someone over here can explain to me what am I doing wrong. This is after reading a lot of articles over the net and doing what the articles say should work but it is not working for me.

I am developing a nice little game with a background music and an explosion sound. For the explosion I know I need to use threads or my music stops when the first explosion happens. I am using threads but the music still stops.

I need the background music to keep on playing all the time and it should continue playing during and after the explosion sound. I tried playing the explosion sync, It doesn't make any difference, the background sound stops playing the second the thread method is triggered.

Here is my code. It is very simple, but the explosion sound is not working.

1. This is the GLOBAL decleration in the *.h file:

   `UINT CMonstersThread(LPVOID Param);`
2. This is the thread function in the *.cpp file:

```
    UINT CMonstersThread(LPVOID Param)
    {
        PlaySoundA("sounds\\expl06.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        AfxEndThread(0);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

3. This is the call for the thread every time a "friendly" is hit, (in the same *.cpp file):

   `AfxBeginThread(CMonstersThread,NULL,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);`

That is all my code. And from what I got over the web, it should work but isn't playing the music continuously while making explosion sounds as I expect it should.

Comment: Some questions (more complete code would help): Are you playing a different sound somewhere before waiting until that one sound is done? Have you looked at playing the sound synchronously instead of asynchronously? Does your thread object die prematurely? It's hard to tell from the code you have posted what is going on. You could also call `PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0)` to block until the current sound is complete.

Comment: sorry, mabye that is the problem? that i don't have all the code needed?, I really don't know....First time using threads in MFC, in java it is so much easy to do things like that.....
For your questians:
1. I need the background music keep on playing, It is playing all the time and sould keep on playing durring and after the explosion.

2. I tried playing the explosion sync, It doesn't make any difference, the background sound stop playing the second the thread method happen.

Comment: 3. I don't mind kiiling the thread or leaving it alive....what even help me solve the problem. I don't need it Until the next hit happen, so i dont see any resone to keep it alive, but i don't mind. I hope that help you to help me some more... 10x :-)

4. From what i know PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0) stopes the current sound...no? how does it help my problem? i need the background sound to stay alive.... :-)

Mabye i didn't understand.....:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using XAudio2 from the latest DirectX sdk to play your audio. I will take a little more work & code, but the end result will be better because you will be able to load the sound file separately from playing it.

With 'PlaySound' you will notice a lag in the audio if you try to use it right after an event, like a mouse click or a monster dying / explosion and you won't hit this with XAudio2. I know this from experience.

Since you are already using Visual Studio, I also suggest you try using VS 2010 if possible because the [Concurrency Runtime, Parallel Pattern Library and Agents Library]][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) make threading and tasking take a little less code.

There are samples as well at http://code.msdn.com/concrtextras and you may find something useful here as well.

-Rick

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to play multiple sounds in parallel using any of the Windows functions like PlaySound or sndPlaySound. As was already suggested, you might want to look at DirectSound or similar APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at using a more full-featured library for your music and sound playing such as [irrKang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/). I am not sure winmm.dll will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see in the code that you posted is that CMonstersThread isn't declared as __stdcall.

You say that some other thread has problems, but without seeing the code it's pretty hard to guess what its problems could be.

Comment: OK, if the destination function calls AfxEndThread then no other component is going to wait for the destination function to clean up the last part of its stack.  But watch out if the destination function terminates in any other way.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but based on the information given, I think his problem is a much simpler issue of a Sound API problem.